# Higher level functions in Go

Tags: go

Given the following Go code

```
type fType = func(interface{}) (*interface{}, error)

func f1(arg interface{}, fun fType) *interface{} {
    r, _ := fun(arg)
    return r
}

func f2(path string) {
    r := f1(path, os.Open) //error
}
```

I get the error in the last line. The error is:

> cannot use os.Open (type func(string) (*os.File, error)) as type func(interface {}) (*interface {}, error) in argument to f1

As further info, below the Visual Studio code screenshot:

[image]

What is my error?

**EDIT**
If I clog f2 with an ugly series of conversions, the code compiles without errors. Is there a more concise and elegant way to achieve the same?

```
func f2(path string) {
    var itfPath interface{}
    itfPath = path
    osOpen := func(p interface{}) (*interface{}, error) {
        var path string
        path = p.(string)
        file, err := os.Open(path)
        var fil interface{}
        fil = file
        return &fil, err
    }
    r := f1(itfPath, osOpen)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is that os.Open is a `func(string)(*os.File,error)`, not a `func(interface{}) (*interface{},error)`. In general, if a `func(interface{})` is required you cannot pass a `func(someOtherType)`, simply because the type signatures don't match. The mechanics of calling a function getting/returning an `interface{}` is different from a function getting a non-interface type.